# How to apply a color transform to textures when using pre-multiplied alpha?

Tags: mathematics, glsl, matrix, fragment-shader, alpha-blending

I'm trying to apply a color map to my textures. The map is a 4x4 matrix that adjusts the contribution of each RGBA channel returned from the fragment shader. My texture needs to use pre-multiplied alpha because it has transparent parts and I don't want artefacts when the color values at opaque/transparent boundaries are interpolated in the fragment shader.

Unfortunately, the only way I've managed to get this to work is by undo-ing the pre-multiplication step in the fragment shader which seems wasteful as it adds overhead (e.g. from the division). I'm wondering if it's possible to avoid this, perhaps by modifying the color map matrix before it's set as a uniform or by using a different blend function?

My blend function is currently: (ONE, ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

I've tried to work through the matrix multiplication with and without alpha pre-multiplication but I get a bit lost. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my (abbreviated) fragment shader code:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform mat4 u_color_map;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);

  // Recover the RGB channels before alpha pre-multiplication.
  color.rgb /= color.a;

  // Apply the color map.
  vec4 mapped = v_color_map * color;

  // Re-multiply by alpha.
  mapped.rgb *= mapped.a;

  gl_FragColor = mapped;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: A quick update: in the end I simplified by using a 3x3 matrix that operates on the RGB channels. I then passed in a separate attribute for opacity which seems fine for my purposes.